# Converting a vue component to a single page application

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to Vue JS and I'm trying to use a vue component [vue-phone](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-phone-number-input) in a single page application. The web server I'm using unfortunately does not support .vue files and I must convert the component into a SPA.

About the web server - it's not specifically a server. It's a 'cloudpage' in Salesforce marketing cloud - that supports html, js, css, json files and nothing much.

Thank you in advance for your guidance.

Comment: If you are using **Vue3** and **Vite**, maybe [this guide](https://vitejs.dev/guide/static-deploy.html) or [this one](https://vuejs.org/guide/best-practices/production-deployment.html#with-build-tools) could help you.

Answer (score 0):

use vue-cli or vite, you need to build your app